# How solve timeout problem in Elastic Search?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, timeout, client, nest

sometimes I have a problem with running Elastic Search in C#. it doesn't work and gets a timeout error. I use the nest library. what should I do with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout can be increased in nest library in each request or you can set a higher timeout in global configuration of Nest.
To set global setting for timeout you can add timeout to the elastic client settings.

For example:

```
 var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, sourceSerializer: JsonNetSerializer.Default);
            _ = settings.MaximumRetries(10)
                    .RequestTimeout(-->Timeout<--);
```

Also each request of Nest can have its own timeout.

These are the way to increase the timeout, but this won't solve the root problem of timeout you have to find the root cause usually you get timeout when your cluster doesn't have enough resources or it is under heavy loads.